# How to start a service using Mac OSX's launchctl

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl

Why does my configuration plist file not load as a service using launchctl?

I am running OSX Yosemite, and I have read this excellent tutorial on using launchctl http://nathangrigg.net/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/

I have created a correct .plist file with the service's configuration (I know this is correct because it's an almost-exact copy of a working plist config file I created several years ago). I type in

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.myservice.plist
```

and get in response

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.myservice.plist: File exists
```

That's not terribly descriptive, but I go and type

```
launchctl start com.apple.myservice
```

and there's no output and nothing happens. I've also tried to use

```
launchctl enable ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.myservice.plist
```

and I just get a

```
Usage: launchctl enable <service-target>
```

in response.

Can someone please reply with the correct syntax for loading a launchd service on OSX Yosemite?

Comment: Maybe `load -w` will help. *"I know this is correct because it's an almost-exact copy of a working plist config file I created several years ago"* -- so, you changed the value for  `Label`, I hope? Are you sure it's not some on-demand service? You'll need to show us the `plist` file. Also, `launchctl enable` does not expect a path; see things like `user/<uid>/[service-name]` in `man launchctl`, or see [What is the difference between a `service-name` and a `service-target`?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166397/what-is-the-difference-between-a-service-name-and-a-service-target).

Comment: Also, make sure the `.plist` file is NOT writable by group and world. And as an aside, if it's not some Apple provided service, then using `com.apple` will just be confusing in the future...

Comment: ...and finally: are you sure the `File exists` is not some output of the process you're trying to run? What does Console say? In the end: we just need to see that `plist` file.

Comment: @Arjan, I forgot to change the label on the .plist file from the previous correct one I used, which explains the "File exists" output. Now that it's changed to the correct label it works as expected. If you wanted to reply to my original question I will accept it as correct.

Comment: you didn't show contents of `com.apple.myservice.plist` so question is what are the rules for system to start your service? How you defined when it should be started?

Answer (score 18):

## Update June 2020

I created a cross-platform tool to handle creating `launchd` and `systemd` service files:

- [serviceman](https://webinstall.dev/serviceman)

## Using launchd

`launchd` can easily get into "weird" states.

- `load` means to *read* the config file and potentially *schedule* a launch.
- `unload` means to `stop` *and* unschedule the config file
- `start` will start the service (ignoring the schedule, I believe)
- `stop` will stop the service (again, ignoring the schedule)

Generally if you want to "restart" it you unload and reload the config like this:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.myservice.plist
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.myservice.plist
```

The `-w` means "write" which means that the change will affect reboots (will load every login or boot... or will not load ever again at login or boot).

If it's a system-level service (in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `/Library/LaunchAgents` you may need to do it with `sudo` (and if you did it without sudo by mistake, you may need to unload it without sudo and then reload it with sudo)

The key in a file that causes it to `start` on `load` is `RunAtLoad` (and `KeepAlive` keeps it running if it dies for some reason)

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
```

It's sometimes tricky to get debug logging from launchctl itself, but the keys `StandardErrorPath` and `StandardOutPath` can at least help you know if your application is dying due to missing or bad information (an unexpanded environment variable or non-writable path, for example). Just be sure that the path you specify is writable by the user running the process.

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/appname-error.log</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/appname-info.log</string>
```

Because they're so hard to debug, I'd recommend using [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) or [launched](http://launched.zerowidth.com/) and mix that with a healthy reading of [launchd.info](http://www.launchd.info/).

Also, there are a number of debugging hints here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/183589/how-do-i-activate-launchd-logging-on-os-x

I haven't tried it yet myself, but this solution looks the simplest:

```
sudo launchctl log level debug 
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into similar problems today.

Simply unload the service and load it again solves the `File exists` problem.

It looks like every time you update a plist file you're gonna have to do that.